# Elasticsearch cluster with Shield - Node not joining to cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have 2 node ELK cluster configured with Shield plugin i.e. LDAP integrated.
Cluster status says yellow. When I run cluster status/health command using curl , I do not see both nodes but only result of that node. i.e. The number of data nodes as 1

elasticsearch.yml Node - 1

```
 cluster.name: TestELKCluster
 node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
 network.host: [_eth0_,_local_]
 index.number_of_shards: 2
 index.number_of_replicas: 1
 shield:
  authc:
    realms:
      ldap1:
        type: ldap
        order: 0
         url: "ldaps://abc.xyz.com:636"
        user_search:
          base_dn: "c=in, ou=abc, o=xyz.com"
          attribute: mail
        group_search:
          base_dn: "c=in, ou=abc, o=xyz.com"
        files:
          role_mapping: "/etc/elasticsearch/shield/role_mapping.yml"
        unmapped_groups_as_roles: false
        user_search.pool.health_check.enabled: false
 shield.audit.enabled: true
 node.master: true
 node.data: true
 discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
 discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["otherELKnodeIP"]
```

Node-2

```
 cluster.name: TestELKCluster
 node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
 network.host: [_eth1_,_local_]
 shield:
  authc:
    realms:
      ldap1:
        type: ldap
        order: 0
        url: "ldaps://abc.xyz.com:636"
        user_search:
          base_dn: "c=in, ou=abc, o=xyz.com"
          attribute: mail
        group_search:
          base_dn: "c=in, ou=abc, o=xyz.com"
        files:
          role_mapping: "/etc/elasticsearch/shield/role_mapping.yml"
        unmapped_groups_as_roles: false
        user_search.pool.health_check.enabled: false
 shield.audit.enabled: true
 discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
 discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["otherELKnodeIP"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this by deleting the system key from master server. We are not using tribe nodes but somehow I generated the system key on ELK master node which was culprit.

Regards,
Vinod